# Java Sockets ServerSide Input

Tags: java, sockets, server

thanks for taking the time to look at my little problem.

I recently got into Java sockets and looked up a simple tutorial for a multi-client chat application found here http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/ its the last example on the page.

It works fine, but i would like to handle server-side inputs too, like disconnect certain users per command or something like that, just "listening" to user input in the server console and i cant seem to wrap my head around that in this specific case.

```
try {
        while (true) {
            new Handler(listener.accept()).start();
        }            
    }
```

if i just check for user input inside the try block it will wait for a user input until a user connects > bad, i want to keep the server in his normal loop until a command is entered.

Is there even any way to do it in this simple example or does it need like an extra thread to listen for user input while still looping through the handlers, and if so, how would i go about this?

Appreciate any help =)

---

EDIT:
Solved the Problem using a different Thread:
First a added a new Class to handle the new Thread which listens for new connections:

```
public class HandleClientsThread extends Thread{

private static int PORT;

public HandleClientsThread(int port) { 
    this.PORT = port;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Handle Clients Thread Start");
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        try {
            while (true) {
                new Client(listener.accept()).start();
            }            
        } finally {
            listener.close();        
        }
    } catch(IOException e) { }
}
```

}

Then all i needed to do in the main Server was to start the thread and let it run in the background while waiting for a user input:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("----- Server running on Port " + PORT + " -----");

    new HandleClientsThread(PORT).start();    

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while(true) {
        String cmd = br.readLine();
        switch (cmd) {
```

If anyone sees any Problems with this like violation some programming patterns or bad stuff that could happen while doing it this way i would appreciate it =)

Answer (score -1):

Another thread would be the most manageable option for you.

The other way is to interrupt the handler thread whenever you wish to perform a different operation and resume/restart the thread when you are done.

Comment: This should probably be a comment rather than and answer.

Comment: i tried my luck with a thread since i couldnt get my head around on how to interrupt the handler thread in the while loop without checking for user input which is not possible while the loop is running. thanks anyway =)